# How to set background material as an object material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do I set an object to render as the background material? As shown in the below images the Sphere and background would render out as transparent in a PNG sequence.

Images are just sample. For my use, boolean or similar doesn't work, so some magic material would be best :)

In old Blender it was known as something like "set background as a material".

Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you show looks like the *Shader > Holdout* node:

[image]

You can also enable the Holdout option in the *Object panel > Visibility > Mask*:

[image]

Also as Vklidu suggests, you can enable the *Holdout* option for a collection in the *Outliner*, remember to activate in the *Outliner*'s filter:

[image]

To make your background transparent, go into the *Render panel > Film*, and enable *Transparent*.

Comment: @vklidu oh yes thanks I forgot this one

Comment: ... too many options :) You can delete me from description to clean it up :)

Comment: Yes!! I completely forgot about holdout!! Huge thanks!!